# HTML style with color green shows red on Android Tablets

Tags: android, html

I know that I should use a css class instead, but this is bothering me and I can't figure it out. Whenever I look on my site on any Samsung Tablet, my green ticks show up as red. The HTML is so simple that I don't understand what's going on other than that this is some kind of weird bug:

```
<span style="color:green;">✔</span>
```

That's all it is. It shows up fine on iPads, Windows 7, Windows 8, various browsers on all of these, but on Samsung Tablets I've tried in the store, it's red.

Anyone any idea?

Comment: what happens if you change green to its hex value?  `#008000`

Comment: I don't have anything handy now to test it with, but I could try next time I go to the store. Would be nice to know if someone here with an Android tablet can confirm it? I tried it with Chrome in the store. No other version of Chrome has the issue though (not on PC, iPad, etc.). Even my Playstation Vita displays it correctly.